# Start ElastAlert with multiple rules

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5, elastalert

I need to start Elastalert with multiple Yaml files not just example_frequency.yaml
Like now to start Elastalert I am giving

```
python3 -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --rule example_frequency.yaml
```

How to start elast alert with all new rules too which i have added not just example_frequency.yaml

Help please

Answer (score 0):

In order to run all the new rules in elastalert, you have to remove `--rule example_frequency.yaml` from your start command.

`--rule example_frequency.yaml` specifies the rule to run, otherwise ElastAlert will attempt to load the other rules in the example_rules folder.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sourav Atta mentioned, if you didn't pass `--rule xxx.yml` then it will load from `example_rules` by default, otherwise, you can add something like this in your `config.yaml` file

```
rules_folder: rules
```

And then execute `elastalert`

```
python -m elastalert.elastalert --verbose --config config.yaml
```

In this case elastalert will load all rules included inside `rules` directory without the need so specify a specific `--rule`